# Can you install PS/2 ports in a PC that didn't come with any?

Tags: ps2

I have a PS/2 keyboard and PS/2 mouse that work quite well. The Dell OptiPlex 780 is an all around excellent PC, but two things it lacks are a) floppy drive by default and b) PS/2 ports.

We have an old dead PC in the basement (a Dell Dimension 8200). I was wondering what I could salvage from it. Dell Technical support said I could salvage the floppy drive from that and put it in an OptiPlex if it didn't come with it by default (most didn't). It also has PS/2 ports, and while I am aware that there are PS/2 to USB adapters and vice versa, I'd like to know **is it possible to take PS/2 ports from an old PC and integrate them into a newer PC that didn't come with any?**

Meaning: is it like a floppy drive where I can just drop it into the new PC and connect the IDE or SATA cable, or is there more fundamental support that needs to be built into a PC  that would prevent you from just transferring the PS/2 ports from an old PC into a new one?

I am aware adapters exist, but again, I only want to know if it's possible to basically add native PS/2 support to newer PCs, using a direct connection to the motherboard, with no adapters.

Comment: So, there is usb to ps2 adapters, or you can make one yourself using the pinouts https://pinouts.ru/InputCables/usb_ps2_mouse_pinout.shtml or you can get a pci card that has ps2 ports on it. You cannot use ide/sata cables for this integration

Comment: @Narzard I specifically said I know about adapters and am not interested. I simply want to know whether it is possible or not to put an actual PS/2 port in a PC that didn't come with them.

Comment: It would be helpful if your post more explicitly stated you want to avoid an adapter.

Comment: It seems like you're already aware of adapters and other alternatives. To answer the question of salvaging, it is highly unlikely because the I/O ports are soldered onto the board. Attempting to remove them could damage the motherboard but maybe you don't care about the old one. Then comes the problem of attaching them to the new motherboard. Your I/O shield and section of the case won't have the room to accommodate them. Since there are no extra circuits just laying around on your motherboard, the PS/2 slots would have no channels to transfer the data.

Comment: @MC10 So, essentially, there is nothing that can be done with the old PS/2 port? Not what I was hoping to hear, but good to know. I'm going right down to the basement to salvage the floppy drive now, and you've spared me some unnecessary trouble in that case (feel free to post as answer)

Comment: @MC10 Twisty Impersonator said so, so I obliged

Comment: @InterLinked From what I understand, there is nothing to be done with an old port that is directly soldered onto the motherboard. It is not modular like a floppy drive or hard drive. Technically you could desolder but that would require an impractical amount of effort for something that an adapter/PCIe card could solve, and the issue of how to get it recognized on the new motherboard still exists. That's beyond me.

Comment: The floppy drive doesn't use SATA or IDE, but has its own specific port – it's exactly the same story as with PS/2 ports (and even handled by [the same chip](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_I/O))...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"is it possible to take PS/2 ports from an old PC and integrate them into a newer PC that didn't come with any?

No most of them are an integral part of the motherboard, unless they used an add in card to get ps2 ports which I have never seen on Dell pc's.

Answer (score 1):

I was also wanting to connect USB-only computers to PS2 (for use with a PS2 KVM switch) and found these dongles. [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00X9QX9MS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00X9QX9MS) .
I know you didn't want an adapter, but the PS2 add-on cards were double or triple the price of these USB dongles so I figured it's worth a shot.